# Can multiple users (not concurrent) utilise the same Amazon WorkSpace?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am looking at AWS Workspaces for some kiosk-style PCs. We have shift workers, so in a single day there might be 3 different people using the workstation.

Can I have a single AWS workspace and share it for 3 different users? They would not be using it concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old.

But I had the same inquiry today and after some research on AWS Workspace documentation I have found the following statement:

> Each WorkSpace is assigned to a single user and cannot be shared by multiple users. By default, only one WorkSpace per user per directory is allowed.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/administer-workspace-users.html